# Construct a function in $L^2\setminus L^1$ such that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)|$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, examples-counterexamples

Construct  a function in $L^2\setminus L^1$ such that $ \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)|$ does not exist.

So we need that $$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|dx = \infty,$$  while
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}|f(x)|^2dx \lt \infty ,$$

and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)|$ does not exist.

I couldn't find such function I tried looking for
"spike" function but fail to find such function.

Comment: You mean $L^2 \setminus L^1$ with `\setminus`, not $L^2 / L^1$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ diverges but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges. From there try to build a piecewise linear map, always vanishing except around $n \in \mathbb N$ where its map is a triangle becoming narrower with $n$. Such a map is also continuous.

> To get a precise example, take a piecewise linear map always vanishing except that
> $$f(x)= 
> \left\{ 
>   \begin{array}{ll} 
>     0 & \mbox{if } x=n-\frac{1}{n^2}\\ 
>     1 & \mbox{if } x=n\\ 
>     0 & \mbox{if } x=n+\frac{1}{n^2}\\ 
>   \end{array} 
> \right.$$ for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: First of all thank you for trying to help, But can you write such function explicitly. i can't seem to do it myself. @mathcounterexamples.net

Comment: I gave a complete example in the answer.

Comment: i think tou need to fix your solution when x=n  if f(x)=1 then it is in L1.

Comment: @eyal It is the case now.

Answer (score 4):

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}+\sum_{n\geq 1} n \exp\left(-n^8(x-n)^2\right) $$
fulfills $f(n)\geq n$ and belongs to $(L^2\setminus L^1)(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Comment: This is not what OP wants.

Comment: Sorry, I read $L^2/L^1$ as $L^2 or L^1$, but it was $\setminus$ instead. Easily fixed.

Comment: Why the limit $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} |f(x)|$ does not exist? and why it is in $L^2$ @Jack D'Aurizio

Comment: @eyal20: it is in $L^2$ by just computing the norms of $\frac{1}{x+1}$ and $ n \exp(-n^8 x^2)$. $|f(x)|$ does not have a limit as $n\to +\infty$ since the values of $f$ at $\mathbb{N}+\frac{1}{2}$ are bounded, the values at $\mathbb{N}$ are not.

Comment: i understand that $|f(x)|$ does not have limit as $\ {n\rightarrow\infty}$ but you need to show that there not exist limit when  $\ {x\rightarrow\infty}$

Comment: If there is no limit along $\mathbb{N}\cup\left(\mathbb{N}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$ there is no limit along $\mathbb{R}^+$, too.